# Order Array in Certain Order PHP

Tags: php, arrays, database, sorting, usort

Currently I am trying to order my array according to each item's value. Now it should be ordered from top to bottom like this: "Platinum", "Gold", "Silver", "Bronze", "None, "Complete", "Uncomplete". Now the problem is after it runs the usort() function it doubles the size of the array. The code I am using is:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM postallions WHERE userid = :userid";
$params = array(':userid' => $userid);
try{
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($params);
}
catch(PDOException $ex){
    echo ("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}
$columns = $stmt->fetch();

$postallionlist = $columns;
unset($postallionlist["userid"]);

print_r($postallionlist);
var_dump($postallionlist);

function compareMedals( $a, $b ) {
    $aMap = array(0 => 'None', 1 => 'Bronze', 2 => 'Silver', 3 => 'Gold', 4 => 'Platinum', 5 => 'Uncomplete', 6 => 'Complete');
    $aValues = array( 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
    $a = str_ireplace($aMap, $aValues, $a);
    $b = str_ireplace($aMap, $aValues, $b);
    return $a - $b;
}
usort($postallionlist, 'compareMedals');

print_r($postallionlist);
var_dump($postallionlist);
```

Now when I var_dump the array before the function it outputs:

```
array (size=22)
  'userid' => string '1' (length=1)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  'p1' => string 'Silver' (length=6)
  1 => string 'Silver' (length=6)
  'p2' => string 'Platinum' (length=8)
  2 => string 'Platinum' (length=8)
  'p3' => string 'None' (length=4)
  3 => string 'None' (length=4)
  'p4' => string 'None' (length=4)
  4 => string 'None' (length=4)
  'p5' => string 'Bronze' (length=6)
  5 => string 'Bronze' (length=6)
  'p6' => string 'Gold' (length=4)
  6 => string 'Gold' (length=4)
  'p7' => string 'Complete' (length=8)
  7 => string 'Complete' (length=8)
  'p8' => string 'None' (length=4)
  8 => string 'None' (length=4)
  'p9' => string 'None' (length=4)
  9 => string 'None' (length=4)
  'p10' => string 'None' (length=4)
  10 => string 'None' (length=4)
```

And print_r:

```
Array ( [userid] => 1 [0] => 1 [p1] => Silver [1] => Silver [p2] => Platinum [2] => Platinum [p3] => None [3] => None [p4] => None [4] => None [p5] => Bronze [5] => Bronze [p6] => Gold [6] => Gold [p7] => Complete [7] => Complete [p8] => None [8] => None [p9] => None [9] => None [p10] => None [10] => None )
```

And those arrays are both perfect. Now after the function it outputs the following: (var_dump then print_r)

```
array (size=22)
  0 => string 'None' (length=4)
  1 => string 'None' (length=4)
  2 => string 'None' (length=4)
  3 => string 'None' (length=4)
  4 => string 'None' (length=4)
  5 => string 'None' (length=4)
  6 => string 'None' (length=4)
  7 => string 'None' (length=4)
  8 => string 'None' (length=4)
  9 => string 'None' (length=4)
  10 => string 'Bronze' (length=6)
  11 => string 'Bronze' (length=6)
  12 => string '1' (length=1)
  13 => string '1' (length=1)
  14 => string 'Silver' (length=6)
  15 => string 'Silver' (length=6)
  16 => string 'Gold' (length=4)
  17 => string 'Gold' (length=4)
  18 => string 'Platinum' (length=8)
  19 => string 'Platinum' (length=8)
  20 => string 'Complete' (length=8)
  21 => string 'Complete' (length=8)

Array ( [0] => None [1] => None [2] => None [3] => None [4] => None [5] => None [6] => None [7] => None [8] => None [9] => None [10] => Bronze [11] => Bronze [12] => 1 [13] => 1 [14] => Silver [15] => Silver [16] => Gold [17] => Gold [18] => Platinum [19] => Platinum [20] => Complete [21] => Complete )
```

So why would the array be doubling after the function?

Comment: Start by changing `$columns = $stmt->fetch();` to `$columns = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` or `$columns = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);` rather than returning both enumerated and associative values.... that way you won't have two entries for every value

Comment: Seems to be working for now :) Thank You! :) I will test it after.

Comment: If you use `$columns = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);` then you'll want to `unset($postallionlist[0]);` rather than `unset($postallionlist["userid"]);`